# I want to push an item in a list if its not there . If the item already in the list then remove that item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to push an item to the list if its not previously included there. If its there then remove that item. I am able to do the first part, but no idea about how to remove that.

```
 handleCityCheckbox = (param1) => {
    var { cityList = [] } = this.state;
      //if cityList doesnt have param1
    if (!cityList.includes(param1)) {
      cityList.push(param1);
      this.setState({ cityList });
    } else  {
      
    }
    this.setState({ cityList });
  };
```

what will be the else part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
handleCityCheckbox = (param1) => {
    const { cityList = [] } = this.state;
    const itemIndex = cityList.indexOf(param1);
    if (itemIndex === -1)) {
      cityList.push(param1);
    } else  {
      cityList = cityList.filter((e, index) => index !== itemIndex)
    }
    this.setState({ cityList });
  };
```

Comment: Nice, happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finished App:

[image]

Filtering function:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      alert("Enter the city name");
      return;
    }
    let tempList = cities.filter(
      (city) => city.toLowerCase() !== name.toLowerCase()
    );

    if (tempList.length === cities.length) {
      tempList.push(name);
      setCities(tempList);
      return;
    } else {
      setCities(tempList);
    }
  };
```

In the above function, we will, first of all, use `filter` function to filter out i.e. delete the city name if it exists and assign it to `tempList`, then we compare the size of `tempList` with main `cities` list, if it's same then it indicates that the city name was not present in the main list so we will push that `name` to `tempList` and update the `cities` state with modified `tempList`, else, we just set the filtered out `tempList`.

Full Example :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState(["Pune", "Delhi"]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      alert("Enter the city name");
      return;
    }
    let tempList = cities.filter(
      (city) => city.toLowerCase() !== name.toLowerCase()
    );

    if (tempList.length === cities.length) {
      tempList.push(name);
      setCities(tempList);
      return;
    } else {
      setCities(tempList);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {cities.map((city) => (
        <p>{city}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-buck-f19fd?file=/src/App.js)